# Wordpress - Insert ACF php

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to insert get_field ACF into PHP code

```
<?php 
$not_human       = "test1";
$missing_content = "test2";
$email_invalid   = "test3";
$message_unsent  = "test4";
$message_sent    = "test5";
?>
```

i need to replace test1 by

```
<?php the_field( 'titre' ); ?>
```

thank you

Comment: You might be looking for the get_field function. The the_field function will automatically render or echo the custom field while the get_field will just get the value of a certain custom field. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the get_field function instead of the the_field.

// https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Example:

```
<?php 
$not_human       = get_field("titre");
?>
```

To echo the value of the $not_human variable containing the custom field titre, do this.

```
<?php 
$not_human       = get_field("titre");
echo $not_human;
?>
```

The the_field function should also work but it looks like you wanted to bind the custom field value to a variable, which is why the get_field function is suggested.